# Fastest way to get indices of a np.array that meet my criteria

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, indices

I am trying to find the fastest way to get the indices of the matrix elements that meet my criteria. 
I have a (7,7) np.array (named "board"), which contains int16 from 0 to 400. For example, I want to find the indices of the elements which are equal to 300.

I have tried many techniques and so far the fastest method is the np.where(board ==300)

The function I am trying to optimize:

```
def is_end(self, board):
    ind = np.where((board > 300) & (board - 300 < 100))
    try:
        victoriousPlayer = board[ind[0][0], ind[1][0]] % 100 // 10
        return victoriousPlayer
    except:
        return -1
```

Because I use this function tens of thousands of times I need it to run as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the indices in this case it seems, just a mask.

```py
ind = np.where((board > 300) & (board - 300 < 100))
victoriousPlayer = board[ind[0][0], ind[1][0]] % 100 // 10
```

is equivalent to

```py
victoriousPlayer = board[(board  > 300) & (board - 300 < 100)][0] % 100 // 10
```

Timings:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                    

In [2]: board = np.random.randint(0,401, (7,7))                                                                               

In [3]: %timeit ind = np.where((board > 300) & (board - 300 < 100));victoriousPlayer = board[ind[0][0], ind[1][0]] % 100 // 10
6.77 µs ± 260 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit victoriousPlayer = board[(board  > 300) & (board - 300 < 100)][0] % 100 // 10                                 
5.02 µs ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: See updated timings. Operations on `np.int16` are slower than on `int64`.

Comment: I did some more testing, it turns out you are Right. I see a ~19% improvement when using int16 and a ~21% improvement when using int64.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to minimize the running time of the function, probably the best you can do is avoid allocating new arrays on each call. That means maintaining additional arrays for temporary values outside of the function, but it does give you a significant speedup.

```py
import numpy as np

# Original function
def is_end_1(board):
    ind = np.where((board > 300) & (board - 300 < 100))
    try:
        victoriousPlayer = board[ind[0][0], ind[1][0]] % 100 // 10
        return victoriousPlayer
    except:
        return -1

# Without array allocation
def is_end_2(board, tmpBool1, tmpBool2):
    np.less(300, board, out=tmpBool1)
    np.less(board, 400, out=tmpBool2)
    np.logical_and(tmpBool1, tmpBool2, out=tmpBool1)
    idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(tmpBool1), board.shape)
    return board[idx] % 100 // 10 if tmpBool1[idx] else -1

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
# Create some data
board = np.random.randint(500, size=(1000, 1000))
# Result from original function
res1 = is_end_1(board)
# Temporary arrays
tmpBool1 = np.empty_like(board, dtype=np.bool)
tmpBool2 = tmpBool1.copy()
# Result from function without allocations
res2 = is_end_2(board, tmpBool1, tmpBool2)
print(res1 == res2)
# True

# Measure time
%timeit is_end_1(board)
# 9.61 ms ± 323 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit is_end_2(board, tmpBool1, tmpBool2)
# 1.38 ms ± 53.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: When I run your code with only changing the dimensions from 1000,1000 to 7,7. My results change to:
6.71 µs ± 94.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
12.8 µs ± 934 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)